# Enable/Disable WPF button based on ListView population

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mvvm

I have defined a button in my `View` (**AXML**) with the following code:

```
<Button Content="Fetch Data" Command="{Binding readInventoryFilesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=browseFolderTextBox}" Name="button1" />
```

The button works as expected but I would like it to be enabled/disabled if a `ListView` has been populated with elements.

- If no elements in the listView --> Button `IsEnabled` set to `false`
- If there are elements in the listView --> Button `IsEnabled` set to `true`

I tried to play around with `IsEnabled="{Binding ...` but I am not getting `code completion` in `Visual Studio C# Express` and it is hard to guess the alternatives.

The command looks like this:

```
internal class ReadInventoryFilesCommand : ICommand
{
    public ReadInventoryFilesCommand(ResourceViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private ResourceViewModel _viewModel;

    #region ICommand Members

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _viewModel.CanUpdate;
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.ReadInventroyFiles(parameter.ToString());
    }
    #endregion
}
```

***EDIT***
This is the current code after Bobs advice:

```
internal class ReadInventoryFilesCommand : ICommand
    {
        public ReadInventoryFilesCommand(ResourceViewModel viewModel)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
            _viewModel.PropertyChanged+= (s,e) => { 
                if (e.PropertyName == "CanUpdate") RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            };
        }

        private ResourceViewModel _viewModel;

        event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged;

        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _viewModel.CanUpdate;
        }

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _viewModel.ReadInventroyFiles(parameter.ToString());
        }

        void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() {
            var handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

It generates the following errors:

```
An explicit interface implementation of an event must use event accessor syntax
```

Comment: Does the command correctly implement canexecute and OnCanExecuteChanged?

Comment: where on earth did you get that canexecutechanged implementation from? Where are you raising the event?

Comment: @BobVale, this is legacy code. That is all the code related to this issue really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise the CanExecuteChanged event from your command when it can execute.

**EDIT**

As gehho mentioned in the comments, you won't need to bind to the buttons IsEnabled property when using the ICommand interface as the Button will use the `CanExecute` function to determine whether it is enabled.

You will however need to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event to inform the command that the value has changed.

**END EDIT**

Assuming `_viewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` you can hook when your viewmodel changes and raise the changed event on your command:

**I've provided two versions, one using the explicit implementation of ICommand the other just implementing the properties and methods without the explicit ICommand prefix.  Both should work.  I would usually use version 2 unless there was a conflict on the methods that had a specific requirement.**

*EDIT VERSION 1 - Explicit Implementation*

```
internal class ReadInventoryFilesCommand : ICommand
{
  public ReadInventoryFilesCommand(ResourceViewModel viewModel)
  {
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    _viewModel.PropertyChanged+= (s,e) => { 
                                  if (e.PropertyName == "CanUpdate") RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                                 };
  }

  event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged { add; remove; }

  private ResourceViewModel _viewModel;

  bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return _viewModel.CanUpdate;
  }

  void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
  {
    _viewModel.ReadInventroyFiles(parameter.ToString());
  }

  void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() {
    var handler = ((ICommand)this).CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

*EDIT Version 2*

```
internal class ReadInventoryFilesCommand : ICommand
{
  public ReadInventoryFilesCommand(ResourceViewModel viewModel)
  {
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    _viewModel.PropertyChanged+= (s,e) => { 
                                  if (e.PropertyName == "CanUpdate") RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                                 };
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

  private ResourceViewModel _viewModel;

  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return _viewModel.CanUpdate;
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    _viewModel.ReadInventroyFiles(parameter.ToString());
  }

  void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() {
    var handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but as explained I am new to this. Where does the different code from above belong to.

Comment: This is to replace your existing definition for the command class

Comment: I tried it and get:
The name 'RaiseCanExecutedChanged' does not exist in the current context Commands\ReadInventoryFilesCommand.cs

Comment: @theAlse it's a typo, I'll correct the answer, it should be `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`

Comment: Maybe it should be mentioned that, when using commands with buttons, it is not required to set the `IsEnabled` property of the `Button` manually. This is done automatically by the `Button` itself based on the return value of the `CanExecute(object)` method of the used `ICommand`.

Comment: @BobVale, please see the edit. You code still generates error.

Comment: @theAlso You've made a typo, you called the event `CanExecuteChange` not `CanExecuteChanged`

Comment: @BobVale, please see the code. It indeed calls `CanExecuteChanged` but it generates error.

Comment: @theAlse No, look at your code, you've missed out the `d` when you delcared the event. You put `event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChange;` not `event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged;`

Comment: @BobVale, I forgot to update everything. The error is something else. Please see updated edit!

Comment: @theAsle Ok that just means you need to add the `{ add; remove; }` to your definition of CanExecuteChanged.  See update, sorry I don't usually end up using the explicit implementations so forgot about that requirement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39635/discussion-between-thealse-and-bob-vale)

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour when binding `IsEnabled` to `Items.Count`.

For example

```
<ListView x:Name="RulesList" />
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=RulesList}" />
```

In this example `Button` will be disabled when the `ListView` has no items and will be enabled when it has 1 or more items.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use binding with converters:
Code Windows1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:CoverterItemsSource2Enabled x:Key="converter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-256,0">
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="196">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=listView, Converter={StaticResource converter} }" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code converter:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class CoverterItemsSource2Enabled : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return false;
            if(value is ItemCollection)
            {
                if ((value as ItemCollection).Count > 0)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However the code uses a command so the `CanExecute` logic should really be handled by the command.

Comment: Yes, but i also read about IsEnabled properties trying, It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?:

```
private void ListView1_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
 {
   Button1.IsEnabled==(ListView1.Items.Count>0);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping this can somehow be done in accordance with the MVVM guidelines, which is to separate code and design!